# Change in switching frequency across gate source

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver, converter

I am working on a bidirectional half bridge DC-DC converter. The converter circuit is shown below.
[image]

I used a TLP250 IC for the driver circuit. A square wave with 20 kHz switching frequency was given as input to the driver circuit. The output from TLP250 is a square wave with 20 kHz switching frequency and 10 V peak to peak.

When I am applying this pulse across the MOSFET (IRF150) in the bidirectional DC-DC converter, the switching frequency of the pulse becomes more than 80 kHz. What might be the reason for this?

Edit:

1. The driver circuit is shown below
   [image]
2. The output pulse from the TLP250(from pin 6)(before connecting the MOSFET) is
   [image]
3. The pulse across gate source of the MOSFET is
   [image]

Comment: Show us the schematic of how you apply the pulses, and give more info about signal/pulse source.

Comment: Welcome! Please show oscillograms showing your gate drive waveforms as well as the 250 kHz you observe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both signals have the same frequency, based on the images you added from your oscilloscope.
Both measurements have a scale of 10us/div and the period of both square waves is approximately 50us which corresponds to 20kHz
Perhaps the automatic measurement is set wrong and you obtained an erroneous measure.